# R - conditionally matching variable values between data frames based on occurrence of regular expression

Tags: r, regex, string-matching

I've hit a bit of a mental block trying to match values between two datasets. Here's an extract of what my data looks like:

```
town <- c("Acworth", "Albany", "Amherst", "Bedford")
weight_factor <- c(0.432, 0.89, 1.3, 0.6777)
df1 <- data.frame(town, weight_factor)
```

as well as this dataframe:

```
name <- c("Peter", "Rob", "Gillian", "Matt", "Louise", "Eva", "Tom")
vote <- c("R", "D", "D", "I", "R", "D", "D")
home <- c("New York", "Florida", "Acworth", "London", "Toronto", "Porto", "Minsk")
weight_factor <- 1
df2 <- data.frame(name, vote, home, weight_factor)
```

Imagine a similar dataset, but with around 300 observations in `df1` and about 10,000 observations in `df2`. What I want to do is grep through the `df2$home` variable to see if there is a match with any of the values of `df1$town`, and, if so, to replace the corresponding value of `df2$weight_factor` with the value of `df1$weight_factor`.

So, if this code executed properly, the new values for `df2$weight_factor`  should be:

```
1, 1, 0.432, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

I've tried achieving this using an if-statement in a for-loop with a grepl command, however this doesn't work as there seems to be a need for an i and a j, however I don't know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you try the match function in R? df1$weight_factor[match(df2$town,df1$town)]

Comment: Hi @Tushar, see my comment on Nicola's post. The problem is that the values of the two different variables don't match up exactly, so match seems like it won't do the trick entirely. Thanks for your advice though, I'm sure match will do the trick for future applications of a similar nature

Comment: @nikUoM I would pre-process the data so that the levels match before doing anything else.

Comment: OK, excuse my stupidity - how would you do that? GSUB? or is there an option for the match command that could match as long as a grep condition is met?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, build correctly your data.frames! It should simply be:

```
df1 <- data.frame(town, weight_factor)
```

and

```
df2 <- data.frame(name, vote, home, weight_factor)
```

There is no reason to use `cbind` (which coerces to a matrix, losing the information about the class of each vector) and then coerce back to a `data.frame`. With the above two data.frames, just try:

```
ind<-match(df2$home,df1$town)
df2$weight_factor[!is.na(ind)]<-df1$weight_factor[ind[!is.na(ind)]]
#     name vote     home weight_factor
#1   Peter    R New York         1.000
#2     Rob    D  Florida         1.000
#3 Gillian    D  Acworth         0.432
#4    Matt    I   London         1.000
#5  Louise    R  Toronto         1.000
#6     Eva    D    Porto         1.000
#7     Tom    D    Minsk         1.000
```

Comment: Damn. Bad news. I just tried this out using my original data, and the problem is that the values don't match up exactly. In other words, if the value in df1 reads "London", the value in df2 might read "London, UK" or "North London". This is why I initially thought grep would be the way to go, as I want the two to match up, even if there are such slight discrepancies, as they mean the same thing substantially (at least for the sake of my work). Thanks so much for helping me out Nicola, I really appreciate all the advice, especially re more efficient code.